# Android Application Crash on button Click

Tags: android, eclipse, button, android-emulator, crash

Hi Ive written a simple android application with two xml pages, one has an image button which ive rigged to open the second xml page when it is clicked. The code returns no errors and runs fine but when I click the button in the android emulator it crashes and asks me to force close. Here is the code I am working on:

First Activity:

```
package com.android.Train;

import com.android.TrainMenu.MenuActivity;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;

    public class TrainActivity extends Activity 
    {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public void goMenu(View v)
    {
      Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MenuActivity.class);
      startActivity(myIntent);
    }    
}
```

First XML File:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/enterButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/button_enter"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="goMenu" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Second Activity:

```
package com.android.TrainMenu;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.android.Train.R;

public class MenuActivity extends Activity 
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);
    }
}
```

Second XML File:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any ideas on why this should crash?

Thanks in advance

I just ran it again, here is the logCat file

```
01-26 14:21:37.784: D/AndroidRuntime(287): Shutting down VM
01-26 14:21:37.784: W/dalvikvm(287): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
01-26 14:21:37.815: E/AndroidRuntime(287): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-26 14:21:37.815: E/AndroidRuntime(287): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
01-26 14:21:37.815: E/AndroidRuntime(287):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
01-26 14:21:37.815: E/AndroidRuntime(287):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
01-26 14:21:37.815: E/AndroidRuntime(287):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
01-26 14:21:37.815: E/AndroidRuntime(287):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-26 14:21:37.815: E/AndroidRuntime(287):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-26 14:21:37.815: E/AndroidRuntime(287):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-26 14:21:37.815: E/AndroidRuntime(287):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-26 14:21:37.815: E/AndroidRuntime(287):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-26 14:21:37.815: E/AndroidRuntime(287):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-26 14:21:37.815: E/AndroidRuntime(287):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-26 14:21:37.815: E/AndroidRuntime(287):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-26 14:21:37.815: E/AndroidRuntime(287):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-26 14:21:37.815: E/AndroidRuntime(287): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-26 14:21:37.815: E/AndroidRuntime(287):  at com.android.Train.TrainActivity.goMenu(TrainActivity.java:23)
01-26 14:21:37.815: E/AndroidRuntime(287):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-26 14:21:37.815: E/AndroidRuntime(287):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-26 14:21:37.815: E/AndroidRuntime(287):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
01-26 14:21:37.815: E/AndroidRuntime(287):  ... 11 more
01-26 14:21:37.815: E/AndroidRuntime(287): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.Train/com.android.TrainMenu.MenuActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
01-26 14:21:37.815: E/AndroidRuntime(287):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1404)
01-26 14:21:37.815: E/AndroidRuntime(287):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
01-26 14:21:37.815: E/AndroidRuntime(287):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
01-26 14:21:37.815: E/AndroidRuntime(287):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2923)
01-26 14:21:37.815: E/AndroidRuntime(287):  ... 15 more
```

Android Manifest.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.Train"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".TrainActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
        android:name=".MenuActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: what is error here ? please put error message here

Comment: Did you declare the second activity in your Manifest file?

Comment: Can you add the messages from the logcat?  You also might want to try to add something to your second layout

Comment: Do you have all your activities added on your Manifest?

Comment: Ive added both the LogCat and the android manifest above, im still getting the same error. Have I declared the activity incorrectly or is it something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its because your `MenuActivity` class is in a different package to your `TrainActivity` class.  I'm not sure how to do it with the package layout you have, but if you had the following:

```
com.ardroid.train.TrainActivity
com.ardroid.train.menu.MenuActivity
```

Then your manifest entry would be:

```
<activity 
    android:name=".menu.MenuActivity "
    android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Comment: Thanks A lot that was the problem, I just had to change the package declaration so that both classes were in the same package. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add both activities in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file .

Comment: Ive posted the manifest above where ive added the second activity is this correct? Im still receiving the same error

Answer (score 0):

i think you have not entered activity in manifest file 
each activity must be there in AndroidManifest.xml file 
such like this

```
   <application  
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity 
        android:name=".TrainActivity "
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

     <activity 
        android:name=".MenuActivity "
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
</application>
```

and if problem then use 
Intent myIntent = new Intent(TrainActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);

Comment: Hi ive updated the question to include my android manifest and logcat file, I am still receiving the activity not found error when I click the button after adding the activity to the manifest?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add the activity to your manifest file (without whitespaces):

```
<activity android:name=".MenuActivity"></activity>
```

Second, for the button itself this is a suggestion for how it could be done:

```
import com.android.TrainMenu.MenuActivity;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;

    public class TrainActivity extends Activity 
    {

    ImageButton button;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.enterButton);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                   goMenu();
            }

        });
    }


    public void goMenu()
    {
      Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MenuActivity.class);
      startActivity(myIntent);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need instanciation ImageButtom on Activty:

```
ImageButton btnImg;

... oncreadte(...) {

btnImg = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.enterButton);

...

btnImg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

// This call new Activity on press ImageButton
Intent it = new Intent(TrainActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
startActivity(it);

}

}
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have classes in different packages.